# How to apply a sort criteria to multiple displays without erase each individual criteria?

Tags: views

I have a view with multiple displays and I have some sort criteria applied to all the displays and one applied individually to each display. Now I have to add one more sort criteria to all displays. But if a I select to apply to all it just erases the individual one.

Is there a way to workaround it? Because it will be a burden to apply to each display individually again.

Ps.: I'm just an end-user, I don't have access to the site's code.

Comment: If you're going through the interface you will have to apply to all and lose individual ones, then reapply them after you sort out the general ones. Or apply individually to all with the new setting, seems like similar effort. Alternative might be to export Views settings so you get text, edit Views in text format (investigate through a test Views if you have to to find out what the new sort criteria is worded), then import the changes and override the original. And of course make backups before changing anything!

Comment: @prkos thank you for your suggestion, I think it could work indeed, but I got no permission to test it (they think I could put the website down and I can't even deny it...). Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Always do testing and development work on your local instance, or a copy of the live site (usually called staged site) if you don't have a local development setup.